# Approximation in the derivation of the Arc Length method

Tags: nonlinear-equations, iterative-method, solid-mechanics

I am studying the proof of the Arc Length method in section 2.2 of this [thesis](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/vasios/files/ArcLength.pdf#page=14). In equation (2.2) the author introduces the supplementary conditions

$$
(\Delta {\bf u} + \delta {\bf u})^T \cdot (\Delta {\bf u} + \delta {\bf u}) + \psi^2(\Delta \lambda + \delta \lambda)^2 \cdot ({\bf q}^T \cdot {\bf q}) = \Delta L^2
$$
thereby adding the final equation to the system

$$
[K_T] \cdot \delta {\bf u} - \delta \lambda \, {\bf q} = -R({\bf u}^\prime , \lambda^\prime)
$$

The author gives the resulting system as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
[K_T] & -{\bf q} \\
2 \Delta {\bf u}^T & 2 \psi^2 \Delta \, ({\bf q}^T \cdot {\bf q})
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta {\bf u} \\
\delta \lambda
\end{bmatrix}
=
- \begin{bmatrix}
{\bf R} \\
\delta \lambda
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Where

$$
A = -[\Delta {\bf u}^T \cdot \Delta {\bf u} + \psi^2 \Delta \lambda^2 \, ({\bf q}^T \cdot {\bf q}) -\Delta u^2]
$$

It seems to me that the terms $\delta {\bf u}^T \cdot \delta {\bf u}$  and $\delta \lambda^2$ have been dropped. Is this because the terms are because they are small and nonlinear? And if so, is this why the Arc Length method is iterative i.e. in order to iteratively eliminate the errors caused by dropping these terms?